# Expand rows on demand in gwt cell table

Tags: gwt

I would like to make celltable to behave like smartgwt's table
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_memo_rows
but i do not want to use smartgwt library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, you'd have to resort to some kind of composite cell rendering the whole row, which can be quite tricky.
This feature should come in GWT by this summer though: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/tKim48mKwGE/P4wj0t-Om5AJ